# Validate javax.validation.* annotated object from external jar in Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework, bean-validation, playframework-1.x, hibernate-validator

I have an entity class which has jsr303 validation annotations. It is compiled against hibernate-validator, then packaged in a jar using maven.

I then have a play 1.2.5 app which includes this jar, and I pass the class to a controller with the argument annotated as @Valid. Play is not seeing any of the validation errors. Is this possibly a problem caused by the way my packages are set up?

Cheers
Nic

Comment: Could you post some example code? It sounds like that you are annotating a method parameter with @Valid? This is not supported with JSR 303. Only Bean Validation 1.1 (JSR 349) standardizes method validation. But maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: The problem was that play's @Valid tags are play-specific, so the play validation system did not consider the bean's jsr303 annotations